How to re-enable viewing image thumbnails in file picker?
In the Gnome on Ubuntu 20, when you opened a file picker (like in Firefox), if you selected an image file, it would show a larger thumbnail in the right-hand side of the file picker modal by default. This was invaluable in helping to confirm you were selecting the correct image.
This feature was extremely useful and saved users a lot of time, so naturally the Gnome developers removed it, as it's no longer available in the Gnome bundled with Ubuntu 22.
Is there any way to get it back? Is the feature completely gone or is it just disabled under some configuration?
